# How to hide and show app bar action buttons

Tags: flutter

I want to hide and show app bar action buttons depending of the context of the page. Probably I need to put the IconButton within another widget, but which one has a property similar to isHidden?

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("Work Order"),
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
    ),
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  ],
),
```

UPDATE:

The easy way is to use empty Container()

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("Work Order"),
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  actions: <Widget>[
    _isDeleteMode ? IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.delete) : Container(),
    ),
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way that I found was to use an empty Container

```
appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Work Order"),
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
    actions: <Widget>[
      _isDeleteMode ? IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.delete) : Container(),
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: Best solution for this case

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the icons from the widget tree altogether using an boolean flag, as follows:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  title: Text("Work Order"),
  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  actions: yourBoolean ? [
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
    ),
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  ] : [],
),
```

Or you can wrap yous icons on a [opacity](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) widget.

Comment: This is an interesting solution. Good to know if I want to remove everything. But, if I want to show one or the other, I think the empty Container is the right solution based on what I just found. What do you think?

Comment: In this case, you will need to dynamically manage the items in the List you pass to the "actions" property. Adding or removing icons is just like adding or removing items from the list. Be aware that bugs can appear when you change a list of widgets several times without passing keys to the list items. Check this video about keys: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kn0EOS-ZiIc